# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 help page requests itself

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When I click on the help icon in my Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 installation, I get the following very weird result:

[image]

It appears as if the help page loads itself, and when I look at my requests through Fiddler, this is indeed what happens. If I go to the help page URL directly (without using the help icon), it works fine. Any idea what might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by a misconfiguration of the CRM installation. To verify this, execute the following query on your Dynamics CRM database:

```sql
SELECT [HelpServerUrl]      
FROM [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[ConfigSettings]
```

The value returned by this query will looks like this: `https://<yourhostname>/help/default.aspx/` The help server URL thus includes the path to the `/help/default.aspx` page. However, if you click on the help icon, Dynamics CRM will append `/help/default.aspx/` to the help server URL. This causes the weird, nesting behavior. It also explains why going directly to the help page does not exhibit this behavior.

The solution is simple: edit the `[HelpServerUrl]` value in the `[ConfigSettings]` table and remove the `/help/default.aspx` part. This will leave just the base server URL in the setting. The final step is to recycle the application pool of the website (as the server URL is cached) and everything works!